# Filter Properties Inside Array of Objects to Properly Display Axes in Parallel Coordinate d3

Tags: csv, d3.js, filter, parallel-coordinates

I am creating a parallel coordinate plot from a csv file. There are a few columns in my csv file that I need for other parts of my script (e.g., ID column to join csv to topojson; StateName so that I know which state's data to display).

Here are the properties for each object in my array:
CVIRISK, ERR_M_YR, FID, FULLSTATE, GEOM, LENGTH

I can create my parallel coordinate plot properly with the values for each of these properties drawing for every record in my csv.

The problem is that I don't want FID, FULLSTATE or LENGTH to have an axis and show up in my PCP.

I want to create a new array of objects that has all the same objects with specific properties removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `source` is the array of objects with all the props, and you want `picked` to be an array of objects with some of those props, you can use `Array.prototype.map` to instantiate new objects with just the props you care about:

```
var picked = source.map(function(d) {
  return {
    CVIRISK:  d.CVIRISK,
    ERR_M_YR: d.ERR_M_YR
  };
});
```